# Mysql query working very slow How can optimize query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, query-optimization

Query:

```
SELECT
  `item`.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.English_name) AS category,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_color.Color) AS Color,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT sub_category.English_name
  ) AS Sub_category,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unit.Name) AS Unit,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_unit.Value) AS Unit_value,
  `gst`.`HSN` AS `GST_hsn`,
  `base_unit`.`Name` AS `Base_unit`
FROM
  `item`
LEFT JOIN
  `gst` ON `gst`.`ID` = `item`.`GST_hsn`
LEFT JOIN
  `item_category` ON `item_category`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN
  `category` ON `category`.`ID` = `item_category`.`Category`
LEFT JOIN
  `item_color` ON `item_color`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN
  `item_sub_category` ON `item_sub_category`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN
  `sub_category` ON `sub_category`.`ID` = `item_sub_category`.`Sub_category`
LEFT JOIN
  `item_unit` ON `item_unit`.`Item` = `item`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN
  `unit` ON `unit`.`ID` = `item_unit`.`Unit`
LEFT JOIN
  `unit` AS `base_unit` ON `base_unit`.`ID` = `item`.`Base_unit`
WHERE
  `item`.`Status` = 'Open'
GROUP BY
  `item`.`ID`
```

If you want to visit schema. Please visit DB schema on sqlfiddle.

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1b1e0/1

I have more than 1500 rows it taking almost 5 sec for execution How can I optimize this query so this query takes less than 1 sec.

Comment: If it was me, I'd get rid of all the GROUP_CONCAT stuff, and instead handle issues of data display in the application code.

Comment: `item.*` <-- this makes your query invalid, because you are not aggregating by all these columns.  With so many joins, and possibly large tables, are you really surprised the query is taking this long?

Comment: there are too many function calls used and there are too many joins as well this will really slow down your query try to look for another way to gather data from db.

Comment: Take the advices of Strawberry and Tim and fix that. If you want additional advices show the explain plan of your query

Comment: @ChristopherPelayo - Function calls and `JOINs` are not, in themselves, villains in performance problems.  Lack of indexes is the problem here.

Comment: @RickJames I disagree.  He is selecting `gst.HSN` and `base_unit.Name`, which may not be functionally dependent on the `item.ID`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I missed those; my Comment is now deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of suitable indexes in the several many-to-many tables is a significant performance problem.  Follow the advice in

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

which says

Do it this way.  (Of course, adapt it to your particular table and column names.)

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

```
⚈  Lack of an AUTO_INCREMENT id for this table -- The PK given is the 'natural' PK; there is no good reason for a surrogate.
⚈  "MEDIUMINT" -- This is a reminder that all INTs should be made as small as is safe (smaller ⇒ faster). Of course the declaration here must match the definition in the table being linked to.
⚈  "UNSIGNED" -- Nearly all INTs may as well be declared non-negative
⚈  "NOT NULL" -- Well, that's true, isn't it?
⚈  "InnoDB" -- More effecient than MyISAM because of the way the PRIMARY KEY is clustered with the data in InnoDB.
⚈  "INDEX(y_id, x_id)" -- The PRIMARY KEY makes it efficient to go one direction; this index makes the other direction efficient. No need to say UNIQUE; that would be extra effort on INSERTs.
⚈  In the secondary index, saying just INDEX(y_id) would work because it would implicit include x_id. But I would rather make it more obvious that I am hoping for a 'covering' index.
```

To conditionally INSERT new links, use IODKU

Note that if you had an AUTO_INCREMENT in this table, IODKU would "burn" ids quite rapidly.

Comment: There are other problems in the query besides this, and if you can't suggest specific indices, this might work better as a comment.